# Event.result as string auto sorts the results I have

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a flex script that basically upon execution prompts the user with an alert message. 
Say my results are something like this:

1) Bajaj,
2) Catalina
3) Anderson
4) Michael

then, the alert prompt auto sorts them and presents the results like this:

"You did so and so for 
 1. Anderson, 
 2. Bajaj
 3. Catalina
 4. Michael"

Essentially the order in which the event was triggered has been sorted by Flex as a courtesy, and I Do not want this sort to happen.

Here is some code to chew upon:

```
<mx:Button label="Save" id="save" width="60" enabled="{showSaveBtn}"
click="saveConfig();" right="0" bottom="0"/>

function saveConfig()
{
// internally calls the function where the alert is supposed to be displayed: 
// doThis
}


private function doThis(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                selectConfigDG.selectedItem = defaultSelectedConFig;
                this.changeConfig = false;
                this.savedMessage.visible = true;
                this.savedMessage.includeInLayout = true;
                this.savedMessage.htmlText = "Configuration " + "<b> \" " + defaultSelectedConFig.description + 
                    " \" </b>" + " has been changed." + " <b> ";

                var resultString = event.result as String;


                if(resultString != null && (StringUtil.trim(resultString)).length != 0)
                {
                    var htmlBody:String = resultString;
                    var alert:Alert = Alert.show(htmlBody,'',Alert.OK);
                    use namespace mx.core.mx_internal;
                    IUITextField(alert.alertForm.textField).htmlText = htmlBody;
                }

                this.savedMessage.validateProperties();         
            }
```

In the above code, what is of interest is event.result as String piece. It basically, sorts this out. I want it to preserve the order. How do I get Flex to do that ?

Comment: Flex will not change a string automatically.  The problem is most likely with how the data is passed back from your service.  You can use a network sniffer such as ServiceCapture or the Flash Builder Network Monitor to validate what actually gets passed back to Flex from your service.

Comment: or you should add a debug on the server side to log what you are sending to the client

Comment: I resolved it, the issue was on the debugger side coz the code was using a HashMap and hence the order was not preserved. I substituted it with a LinkedHashMap. Thanks for yer help :)